# LSTM Sequence to sequence anomaly detection

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, anomaly-detection

I have a simple dataframe and want to build my LSTM architecture, so that I can do an anomaly detection

```
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, LSTM, RepeatVector,TimeDistributed
from keras import optimizers
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

X = array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 25, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]) 
X_train = X.reshape(1, 8, 1)
y = X.reshape(1, 8)
```

I am expecting my LSTM encoder should tell me the anomaly at data point 25 while it will try to learn the sequence

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(8, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
print(model.summary())

history = model.fit(X_train, y, epochs=500, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
result = model.predict(X_train, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
```

And the results are

```
[0.6, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 2.4, 1.1, 1.3, 1.2]
```

Which is not looking like an anomaly to me at data point 25

What changes I should make in my architecture so that it will clearly come up

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you didn't get the error for the shape of your labels.

Anyway, increasing the units solves the problem.

`y = X.reshape(1, 8, 1)`

`model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(8, 1), return_sequences=True))`

`print(result)`

`[[[ 0.3147867 ] [ 0.40975055] [ 0.19347075] [ 0.43266642] [24.969408 ] [ 0.5055496 ] [ 0.61411744] [ 0.72490424]]]`

But, this is only one training example. I would suggest to use bigger dataset with training and validation set and check the validation loss.